# Using SQL unpivot on two groups

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I have a table as below:

```
Name    ValueA1    ValueA2    ValueA3    ValueB1    ValueB2    ValueB3    QtyA1    QtyA2    QtyA3    QtyB1    QtyB2    QtyB3
John    1          2          3          4          5          6          100      200      300      150      250      350
Dave    11         12         13         14         15         16         100      200      300      150      250      350
```

I am able to use `unpivot` to get the values:

```
select [Name]
     , Replace(u.[Period],'Value','') as [Period]
     , u.[Value]
from Table1
unpivot
(
  [Value]
  for [Period] in ([ValueA1], [ValueA2], [ValueA3], [ValueB1], [ValueB2], [ValueB3])
  ) u;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56fbc/5)

However I'm trying to get both the `Value` and `Qty` columns on a single row, what I want to end up with is:

```
Name    Number  Value   Qty
John    A1      1       100
John    A2      2       200
John    A3      3       300
John    B1      4       150
John    B2      5       250
John    B3      6       350
Dave    A1      11      100
Dave    A2      12      200
Dave    A3      13      300
Dave    B1      14      150
Dave    B2      15      250
Dave    B3      16      350
```

What I have so far is (which doesn't work at all):

```
select [Name]
     , Replace(u.[Period],'Value','') as [Period]
     , u.[Value]
     , u2.[Value]
from Table1
unpivot
(
  [Value]
  for [Period] in ([ValueA1], [ValueA2], [ValueA3], [ValueB1], [ValueB2], [ValueB3])
  ) u

 unpivot

 (
   [Qty]
   for [Period] in ([QtyA1], [QtyA2], [QtyA3], [QtyB1], [QtyB2], [QtyB3])

 ) u2;
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible with `unpivot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple apply for this by specifying the pairs in a values clause:

```
declare @table table (Name varchar(10), ValueA1 int, ValueA2 int, QtyA1 int, QtyA2 int);
insert into @table
select 'John', 1, 2, 100, 200 union all     
select 'Dave', 11, 12, 100, 200;


select  Name, Number, Value, Qty 
from    @table
cross 
apply   (   values 
            ('A1', ValueA1, QtyA1),
            ('A2', ValueA2, QtyA2)
        ) c (number, value, qty);
```

> If you're using an older edition of MSSQL, you might need to use this
>    instead of the values clause above:
>
> ```
> cross 
> apply (   select 'A1', ValueA1, QtyA1 union all
>           select 'A2', ValueA2, QtyA2
>       ) c (number, value, qty);
> ```

**Returns:**

```
Name    Number  Value   Qty
John    A1      1       100
John    A2      2       200
Dave    A1      11      100
Dave    A2      12      200
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, even when expanded to 12 columns!